What majority age is taken into consideration when travelling from country to country?
I asked the following question here in travel StackExchange but was advised to also post it here to receive more accurate answers

Multiple countries have differing ages, and citizens are considered to have reached the majority age and thus can travel without parental authorization. In most countries, the age is 18, but in the country I live in, it's 19, and if you are below that age, then you will need parental authorization to travel from my country to another one.
But what if I traveled to a country like the UK, where the majority age is 18, from my country and I needed parental authorization to do so, now I'm in the UK and planning to travel to a country like Malaysia, where the majority age is also 18.
Will I need parental authorization or not?
Additional Info:
I am 18 years old
My country is Algeria
The country I will travel from is the UK
The country i will travel to is Malaysia for 60 days

Didn't you already get parental authorization when you traveled to the UK?

@Barmar that authorization was only for traveling from Algeria to the UK.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
